# How to get rows in the correct order when using RowNum in where clause

Tags: oracle

The below query returns me large set of records. I only want to get 100000 as fast as possible in exactly that specific order. When i use where RowNum < 100000, the order gets messed up for obvious reasons.

How do I change the below query to return in the right orderby and only limit to get 100000 records. Please advise. Thanks

```
SELECT S.LOGIN_ID as LoginId, S.ProductId as ProductId, P.CREATE_DT as CreateDate, 
FROM SITE_USER S
INNER JOIN Production P on P.LOGIN_ID = S.LOGIN_ID
where P.PROCESS_CD = 'REGISTRATION' 
and P.CREATE_DT >= '20-JAN-21'
order by P.Request_id asc
```

Comment: What's the db version you're running on? Only v12 and newer can understand FETCH

Comment: Huh, I dont know what version. maybe I should find that out. If its newer, my query looks good for you, @ekochergin

Comment: Ok. Its Oracle 11.. I will change the question then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're running on v11, you can't use FETCH but you can limit the sub-query.

```
select * from (
    SELECT S.LOGIN_ID as LoginId, S.ProductId as ProductId, P.CREATE_DT as CreateDate, 
      FROM SITE_USER S
     INNER JOIN Production P on P.LOGIN_ID = S.LOGIN_ID
     where P.PROCESS_CD = 'REGISTRATION' 
       and P.CREATE_DT >= '20-JAN-21'
     order by P.Request_id asc)
where rownum <= 10000;
```

UPD. And check please if this condition will work

```
and P.CREATE_DT >= '20-JAN-21'
```

if p.create_dt of date type, you need to update it to something similar to this

```
and P.CREATE_DT >= to_date('20-JAN-21', 'dd-MON-yy')
```

Comment: Thanks.. but will this limit to 10000 after getting all million records or it considers the rownum while running the query in the brackets ?

Comment: It worked just great with "and P.CREATE_DT >= '20-JAN-21' "

Comment: I believe it considers rownum while running the subquery. There will be "SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY" step in the execution plan

Comment: @challengeAccepted and you'll see entries like "filter(ROWNUM<=10000)" in explain plan as well